# Loading Ext.JS4 only when needed with Ext.onReady

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, loader

Goal:
Load Ext Framework (JS File) only when needed.

Problem:
When loading Ext.JS at a later state Ext.onReady doesn´t fire. I tried working around Ext.onReady, which I didn´t get to work either. I´d be happy for any insight. I´ve also tried various loaders other than jQuery.

The non-working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/XNJxT/21

Same example, but loading Ext.JS immediately (works):
http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/WvcZu/1/

Same example, later load of grid, but immediate include of JS (works):
http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/WvcZu/2/

Comment: When manually telling Ext that it´s ready, the grid in this example works... http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/XNJxT/22/ Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Ext loader is not made for that kind of thing. You're gonna have to tell Ext explicitly that the DOM is already loaded:

```
$().ready(function () { Ext.EventManager.fireDocReady(); });
Ext.onReady(...
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps in most cases... :)